# Progress bar not incrementing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have the following code which read a file and also increment the progress bar while reading it, but I don't see any activity in my `progressBar`. Why is this?

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
progressBar1.Maximum = (int)fileStream.Length + 1;
progressBar1.Value = 0;

using (fileStream)
{
    fileStreamLength = (int)fileStream.Length + 1;
    fileInBytes = new byte[fileStreamLength];
    int currbyte = 0, i = 0;
    var a = 0;
    while (currbyte != -1)
    {
        currbyte = fileStream.ReadByte();
        fileInBytes[i++] = (byte)currbyte;
        progressBar1.Value=i;

    }

 }
```

Comment: your code is running in the same thread as UI thread, use multi-threading to solve this.

Comment: Be careful with the thread you're doing all this in (is it the UI thread?). Also, if you post a small working (non-working which is supposed to be working) example, your chances for being helped would be greater.

Answer (score 2):

It is incrementing but you cannot see it. It is caused by running your loop in UI thread.
Look for BackGroundWorker or async/await pattern.

Answer (score 0):

User `Method Invoker` to update the UI...
try this...

Do all the your work in a thread and when updating the `progressbar` use the following lines...

For Windows Forms

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
{
progressBar1.value=i;
});
```

For WPF

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
{
progressBar1.value=i;
}));
```

Comment: `.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type '.MainWindow' could be found.`

Comment: I think this will help you, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: its from ` System.Windows.Forms` i am using `WPF`

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
                {
                    prograssBar1.Value=i;
                }));

Comment: [MethodInvoker in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

your best option will be `Background Worker`.
drag and drop a `BackgroundWorker` from toolbox. then you have to implement 2 function:   one is doing the background work, another is for reporting to UI.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the BackgroundWorker.
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        // begin reading your file here...

        // set the progress bar value and report it to the main UI
        int i = 0; // value between 0~100
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    // Set the text.
    this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
}
}
```